# Create AWS credentials programmatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I understand how to create an AWS profile (with some access keys) on a machine locally through the command line. I 'm just wondering if there is a way to do it through the JAVA SDK.

Comment: What do you mean by "create an AWS profile"? Are you referring to creating the `.aws/credentials` file, or are you talking about calling the AWS service to generate STS credentials? What CLI command are you using? Feel free to Edit your question to provide more details.

Comment: From CLI, we can do aws configure --profile myprofile. I would like to be do this programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `aws configure` command is simply storing information in the `.aws/credentials` 
 and`.aws/config` files. You can programmatically create those files if you wish — they are just text file. There are no API calls involved.

For the contents and format of the file, see: [Configuration and Credential Files - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html)

**~/.aws/credentials**

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
```

**~/.aws/config**

```
[default]
region=us-west-2
output=json
```